# google app engine taking too much time in giving response from endpoint android

Tags: java, android, performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

In my android project i have started building google cloud endpoints.
But the response time is very slow. It is taking 21 seconds to fetch the response from server.

```
  private class GetListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        try {
            System.out.println("fetching list>>>");
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
             service.list().execute();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Total Time took:>" + ((end - start) / 1000));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }       
}

 02-05 18:18:52.130 3261-4995/com.abc I/System.out: Total Time took:>21
```

Comment: Are you connecting to an Automatic Scaling (Frontend) Instance?

Comment: Yes I am using automatic scaling .....

Comment: Does it always take 21 seconds even when the instance is up and running?

Comment: No  if i hit api request continously  then response time is less ranging less then second to 3-7 seconds...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to the latency of the instances. App Engine has to spin up an instance when you request your API for the first time. When the request is finished the instance will shutdown after a while. Maybe you can try the following suggestions

https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-reduce-latency-of-your-google-cloud-endpoints-apis-5bbe66385e32#.omt015ab8